# "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" when creating files in a temporary directory

Tags: windows, rust

I consistently  get the following error on Windows (both local and inside Github Actions). I do **not** get this error on macOS and Linux.

```
Error: Custom { kind: Other, error: PathError { path: "C:\\Users\\RUNNER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\.tmpi45reT", err: Os { code: 32, kind: Other, message: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." } } }
```

The code is basically creating a temporary dir with `tempfile` crate and then doing a bunch of `File::create`s in that directory (and some other, probably irrelevant stuff). After all writes each file is explicitly `drop`ped and the dir handle is explicitly `close`d. Here's the rough version of the code:

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=91005019c5d60c90b6771536d29a5fb3)

```rust
use fs::File;
use std::env;
use std::fs;
use std::io::Write as _;
use tempfile::tempdir;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let dir = tempdir()?;
    let dir_path = dir.path();
    let pkg_path = dir_path.join("package.json");

    let mut pkg_json = File::create(pkg_path)?;

    pkg_json.write_all(
        r#"
    { 
        "name": "testpackage"
    }
    "#
        .as_bytes(),
    )?;

    let _a = File::create(dir_path.join("yarn.lock"))?;
    let _b = File::create(dir_path.join(".gitignore"))?;

    env::set_current_dir(&dir)?;

    drop(pkg_json);

    drop(_a);
    drop(_b);

    dir.close()?;

    Ok(())
}
```

This is a part of integration tests, where each test does something similar to the code above.

What could be causing this error?

Comment: You should identify *which* of the multiple error points are reporting the error. Switch from `?` to `.expect()` for the simplest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the reason was not changing the current directory back to where it was after manually setting it to the tmp directory.